# Google chart not showing up on Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-visualization

so, I'm sending this data to the frontend from my view:

```
data = [["Name", "Ammount"], 
        ["x", 0], 
        ["y", 2],
        ["z", 1]]
```

And I'm trying to show this as a bar graph to my user, but nothing is showing up (literally, It's blank where the graphic was supposed to be).

My html looks like this:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href={% static "assets/icon.ico" %} />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href={% static "css/styles.css" %} rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_decision_type);     
            function drawChart_decision_type() {
                var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{ my_data|safe }});
    
                var options3 = {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Stuff',
                        subtitle: 'Test',
                },
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
                };
    
                var chart3 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_materia'));
    
                chart3.draw(data3, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options3));
            }

        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
                <div class="card_view">
                    <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div>
                </div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Core theme JS-->
<script src={% static "js/scripts.js" %} ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are other things on my html code, but nothing that comes to mind as important. Just some hyperlinks that connect the user to other pages, should not be a huge influence on this problem alone.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the view code.

Comment: any errors in the browser's console? (press F12)